# Change @PropertySource value in run time

Tags: java, spring, reflection, junit, spring-boot

How can I change the value of @PropertySource in run time when the junit test case runs. For example,

I want to replace the value of below,

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:${app.deploy.env}/sample/mine.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

with

```
value = "classpath:sample/mine.properties"
```

when junit test runs.

Comment: why do you want to do that ? Can you provide the code and explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Umm... why not use this the intended way? Put expressions for all dynamic parts e.g.: `value = "${protocol}:${app.deploy.env}/sample/mine.properties"` and switch the values for ${protocol} between _file_ and _classpath_ based on environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that if you really want to but I'd not recommend you to do that this way. You first need to figure out which `PropertySource` contains the value. Since you have that annotation in your example, a `PropertySource` will be added to the regular ones, probably as the first instance.

You can inject the `Environment` in a managed bean where you want to make that change as a `ConfigurableEnvironment` and retrieve the `PropertySource` via un call to `getMutablePropertySources()` on the environment.

Having said that. Why? How is changing such fundamental property of your application is representative of what is going to happen in your app. It looks like you are using the Spring runner and you'd like to start your app with different settings in different test methods. If that's what you want to do, do not use the runner but manage the context yourself, it's really not that hard.

For instance, here are [JMS-related tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/4697432edd22283eabea3c7191690bc510122eda/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisAutoConfigurationTests.java) that change the `Environment` to test various scenarios. You can [easily load the context with a specific set of keys](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/4697432edd22283eabea3c7191690bc510122eda/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisAutoConfigurationTests.java#L102-L103) and a [`@After` method makes sure to shutdown the context for each test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/4697432edd22283eabea3c7191690bc510122eda/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisAutoConfigurationTests.java#L72-L77).

We use this pattern quite a lot in Spring Boot. As a matter of a fact, I have a JUnit rule that facilitates all that on my todo list for months now.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have property file under resource directory and then under config directory for different environments such as dev, qa. My application is build as a debian package and while install it in different environment it start the spring boot jar with start up scripts and pass java arguments such as app.deploy.env. So when junit runs in jenkins with I want to say that load the property file under resource and runs the unit tests.

Comment: I also find that I can pass the java argument with maven build command know. So I thought of build my application with app.deploy.env point to property file under resource folder so that unit test runs successfully too. Its simple and I dont have to change @PropertySource value in runtime too.